# .NetCore MariaDb Dapper - How to Execute Stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc, mariadb, dapper

I have an issue executing a stored procedure using Dapper with Mysql (MariaDB).

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `user` @`%`
PROCEDURE database.`proc_EnterRow`(
   IN `_entity_number`    INT(11),
   IN `_price`            DECIMAL(19, 13),
   IN `_valuation_date`   DATETIME)
   LANGUAGE SQL
   NOT DETERMINISTIC
   NO SQL
   SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tablename (entity_number,
                         entity_name,
                         valuation_date,
                         units,
                         price,
                         investor_code,
                         currency,
                         provisional,
                         isin,
                         type,
                         batchno,
                         maturity_date,
                         fx_rate,
                         transaction_id,
                         bond_reserves,
                         bond_reserves_percentage,
                         bond_reserves_conv,
                         sold,
                         verified)
     SELECT entity_number,
            entity_name,
            _valuation_date,
            units,
            _price,
            investor_code,
            currency,
            provisional,
            isin,
            type,
            batchno,
            maturity_date,
            fx_rate,
            transaction_id,
            bond_reserves,
            bond_reserves_percentage,
            bond_reserves_conv,
            sold,
            verified
       FROM tablename2 v
      WHERE v.entity_number = _entity_number`;
END;
```

The stored procedure works fine when I execute from an sql editor using

```
call proc_EnterRow(111,123.5456,'2021-07-09');
```

But when I call it from my .Net Core with Dapper ORM I keep getting the error message

> Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE database.proc_EnterRow; expected 3, got 0

My code .Net code

```
DynamicParameters_parameters = new DynamicParameters();
_parameters.Add("@_entity_number", 111, DbType.Int32, SetDirection(parameterDirection), 11);
_parameters.Add("@_price", 123.5501, DbType.Decimal, SetDirection(parameterDirection));
_parameters.Add("@_valuation_date", "2021-01-01", DbType.Date, SetDirection(parameterDirection);
_dapper.Execute("dbname.proc_EnterRow", _parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello @Roddy could you please share your code, how you are executing `proc_EnterRow` in `asp.net core` code?

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

```
var resulst = _dapper.Query<YourEntity>("dbname.proc_EnterRow", 
                                        new { _entity_number = 111, _price = 123.5501, _valuation_date = 2021-07-09}, 
                                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your are trying to execute a stored procedure on your Maria Db from ASP.NET Core.

You are getting the error because the stored procedure parameters haven't been passed exactly.

You could try this way:

```
string name = "Kiron Test";
int employeeId = 520520;
int totalPrint = 10;

var enterNewRowInDb = new List<PrinterJob>();
enterNewRowInDb = _context.PrinterJobs
                          .FromSql("proc_EnterRow {0}, {1},{2}",name,employeeId,totalPrint)
                          .ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Another way:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerName;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "proc_EnterRow";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", employeeId);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrint", totalPrint);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

**Note:** it won't return your select query data. To get that you have to execute a data reader operations.

Hope it would help you. Let me know if you any further concern.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the information I will check that out surely.